# Supremum and Infimum Proof: $\inf(x) + \sup(y) \leq \sup(x+y)$

Tags: analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Im stuck on how to prove this:

> $$\inf(x) + \sup(y) \leq \sup(x+y)$$

I know that

$$\inf(x) \leq \sup(x)\\
x \leq y\implies \sup(x) \leq \inf(y)\\
\sup(x) + \sup(y) \geq \sup(x+y)\\
\inf(x) + \inf(y) \leq \inf(x+y)\\
x \leq y\implies \sup(x)\leq \sup(y)$$

How can I utilize these to prove this?

I've come to the conclusion that
$$\inf(x)+\inf(y) \leq \inf(x+y) \leq \sup(x+y) \leq \sup(x) + \sup(y)$$

I've also tried utilizing the $\sup(x) = -\inf(-x)$ proof, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, $\inf x+\sup x\leq \sup(x+y)$ is not true.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews *** Correction inf(x) + sup(y) ≤ sup(+)

Comment: Are $x,y$ in the same set or different sets? Are you given $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$?

Answer (score 1):

We can prove so by definition. For any $\epsilon>0$, there is $u\in y$ so that 
$$\sup(y) - \epsilon < u$$

For this $u$, pick any $v\in x$,
$$\inf(x) +\sup(y) - \epsilon < v + u \le \sup(x+y).\tag{1}$$
Since (1) holds for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have
$$\inf(x) + \sup(y) \le \sup(x+y).$$